# Whats wrong with the camera in recent ISS videos?

Tags: iss, camera

In recent videos from the ISS, specifically videos after the recent Demo 2 docking, there are what seems to be little particles stuck inside or on the camera lens. I am wondering, is this damage from radiation to the camera?  For an example, check out

. It is fast forwarded to a good point, Look at the man in the middle's left leg, there is a white dot that is caused by the camera.

[image: Camera Damage]

Comment: I have watched this on various devices and cannot see what you are talking about, sorry.

Comment: Can you annotate a still?  I don't see what you are referring to.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I added a image with the phenomenon circled. If you watch these videos long enough you can tell that these don't move with the background and are static.

Comment: I've borrowed your video here: [Are there really “Dead End” signs on the outside of the International Space Station?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45649)

Comment: I don't have a source, but it's my understanding that this is indeed radiation damage.  You see this degradation in most all of the video from cameras on the ISS.

Comment: Most of the cameras on the ISS, especially the older ones, have accumulated quite a bit of radiation damage over the years. This damage manifests itself in "stuck" or broken "pixels" on the camera's sensor.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed radiation damage. NASA has a short writeup of it [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20070022613/downloads/20070022613.pdf).

They speculate a variety of factors affect the rate of dead pixels:

- Imager size
- Pixels per imager
- Shape and size of individual pixels
- Pixel shifting and interpolation
- Imager type CCD or CMOS
- Error correction and concealment methods
- Compression techniques used in recording and
  transmission
- Temperature of imager

An image of total dead pixels for one example camera is also provided:

[image]

Some of the longer running experiments that rely on imagery for their science return (such as the Combustion Integrated Rack) have mapped out dead pixels in their cameras and compensate for them in their data processing.

Comment: Is that what is seen in [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOQgV.jpg) of a Cygnus docking? I thought at first it might be stars but that wouldn't quite make sense based on the camera brightness setting with Cygnus in view, plus the fact that the different "star" colors look like Christmas lights.

Comment: @StevePemberton Yes, most of the external cameras have significant radiation damage as shown in the image you linked.