# Are there really "Dead End" signs on the outside of the International Space Station?

Tags: iss, astronaut-lifestyle, eva

[This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45648/12102) currently links to the NASA video [Expedition 63 Inflight interview with Yahoo Finance KPRC TV - July 24, 2020](https://youtu.be/qhbOuEBA3Zs?t=466) at `07:46` where a few seconds later Expedition 63 NASA Flight Engineers Robert Behnken says:

> I will tell you that both Chris and I remarked that on some of the work sites we had we were pretty far out, I know other astronauts have been out to the edge of the space station before, but it really is something that you are aware of; that you are on the very edge of the space station. **Some of the signs out there say "Dead End".**

I've seen photos of the speed limit signs on the *interior* of the ISS, but never a similar traffic-like sign on the exterior, let alone a proper DEAD END sign. ([When was the ISS's "SPEED LIMIT 17500 MPH" sign originally posted?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31366))

**Question:** Is this literally true? Are there really "Dead End" signs on  the outside of the International Space Station? Or are the warnings at the ends of the station exterior more official sounding? Or are there actually no warning signs about "the end of the space station" at all.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

"The dead end label is used to identify a translation path that has no other exit, or dead ends."

Note it does not necessarily refer to the absolute end of the ISS.

[image]

Source: [Decal Process Document And Catalog](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/495093main_Decal-Catalog-JSC-27260-RevF.pdf)

Here is an example of one of the Dead End stickers, it is on PMA-2.

[image]

Image Source: [images.nasa.gov](https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/S100E5264/S100E5264%7Eorig.jpg)

Cropped and annotated by me

[image]

Comment: like this one! :-)

Comment: I think it's interesting that the dead end signs, unlike the interior "speed limit" signs, seem to be entirely practical rather than whimsical.